# Algoritmo para ajustar dos "sliders" sin repeticiones

Tags: php, array, windows, algoritmos, slide

No se si es un algoritmo tipo "sliding window".

La idea base es:

se va a mostrar el contenido de un array en dos sitios a la vez, a distintas velocidades. Es decir, tengo dos "sliders" que muestran el mismo contenido.

pongamos que partiendo de un array como $lista, se generan dos arrays:

```php
// Partiendo de este.
$lista = ['A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'];

// Tenemos estos dos, con un desfase entre el primero y el segundo.
$slider1 = ['A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'];
$slider2 = ['B', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'A'];
```

`$slider1` pasara de un elemento a otro cada 14 segundos.
`$slider2` pasara de un elemento a otro cada 10 segundos.

El Problema es que pasado un tiempo, de manera ciclica, se muestra el mismo contenido en ambos arrays durante un tiempo.

El problema, o la cuestion, es si con estos datos, hay ya algun algoritmo conocido. O si hay algoritmos similares que puedan servirme de guia... He buscado con poco exito.

Creo que la descripcion seria:

Dada una lista de elementos ordenados.
- mostrar en A ciclicamente un elemento de la lista cada X segundos empezando desde el primero.
- mostrar en B ciclicamente un elemento de la lista cada Y segundos empezando desde el segundo.
- no puede estar mostrandose el mismo elemento a la vez en A y en B.

El algoritmo puede/debe alterar el listado que se muestra en A y/o en B ($slider1 y $slider2). cambiando el orden, añadiendo mas veces los mismos elementos. pero estos no pueden ser consecutivos.

```php
// Esto seria valido
$slider1 = ['A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'];
$slider2 = ['B', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'E'];
$slider2 = ['B', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C'];

// Esto no seria valido.

$slider1 = ['A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'];
$slider2 = ['B', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'];
```

Comment: El problema no es tanto un algoritmo, sino que estás usando el mismo orden para los elementos: A, B, D, E, F, G aunque en diferente posición, entonces, va a llegar un momento en que ambos sliders se vean iguales. ¿No bastaría con poner orden inverso al segundo slider?

Comment: @Triby gracias por tu respuesta, pero me temo que no es esa la solucion. Incluso poniendo el segundo slider en orden inverso. el problema es tener dos arrays con los mismos elementos, aunque sean en distinto orden, que se van recorriendo ciclicamente, a distinta velocidad. Un array se recorre mas rapidamente que el otro. Y en algun momento ambos arrays estan en el mismo elemento. Eso es lo que quiero evitar. Al tener el mismo array, mismo orden, pero desplazado un valor, creo que es mas facil hacer un algoritmo para evitar repeticiones.

Comment: Pues no. Necesariamente, en algún momento, ambos sliders van a mostrar lo mismo, tal vez puedas retrasarlo, pero va a pasar porque son muy pocos elementos.